# How to recover lost g-suite docs

Tags: g-suite

Occasionally people in my organisation will report that files they have previously had access to have suddenly vanished.

They're often not sure who originally owned the document.

What I will typically receive from them is a link they've previously used, which now reports a 404 error.

Given just a google doc link, is there any way I can attempt to recover the files, considering I may not know who owned it?

I understand that there is a limited period of time after a document has been deleted, before it becomes un-recoverable. However if the file has only just been deleted, there aught to be some way to get it back.

I've tried going to ....

Apps > G Suite > Settings for Drive > Team Drives

and then filtering by deleted. However it doesn't show me the files I'm looking for.

What is the next step? Is there some way I can do an advanced search based on the ID from the URL?

In the past the response has simply been, "I'm sorry the file is simply gone". However this really isn't good enough. I feel like I don't have any visibility into how Google manages these files, and this makes me very nervous. Having no way to recover deleted files, just seems unacceptable.

As far as I'm aware I have no way to be notified when files are going to be permanently deleted, so I have no way to try to back things up to more permanent storage.

I'm almost to the point of advising the relevant people that we need to move away from g-suite for our documents, as the risks of catastrophic file loss is just too high. This would be a massive hassle though.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

How much time it has been the files are deleted because the deleted files can be restored up to 25 days and if this time span exceeds more than 30 days they are permanently deleted from Team Drive Trash too. 
You can check more about recovering files if having vault policies from https://support.google.com/a/answer/7376096?hl=en

Comment: I've had a look at this URL, and followed the instructions. However it appears to only show deleted team drives, rather than individual files. I tried creating a file and then deleting, and I've verified that I could not see or recover it through "Manage Team Drives", as advised.

Comment: The users have only lost access to these files in the last day or so. However I just cannot find any way to actually recover the files.

Comment: Are you sure you are signed in with work account or Admin account of Gsuite??